# Simplexml PHP - get value of a "deep node"

Tags: php, xml, magento, simplexml

This is driving me crazy. I could have copied and pasted the 2 values I need and been done with this 30 minutes ago, but instead I'm trying to do it "right".

There is only ONE "username" in the entire file. How do I get it? I tried using xpath (  `$username=$xml->xpath('default_setup/connection/username');` ) and I tried chaining the nodes up to it ( $username=$xml->{...full path here...}->default_setup->connection->username;` ).

When I `print_r($xml)`, I can see all the nodes I want and their values. When I `print_r($username)` I get nothing.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('database.xml',NULL,LIBXML_NOCDATA); // connection details are inside of CDATA

$username=$xml->xpath('default_setup/connection/username'); ?>
<p>Username: <?= (string)$username ?></p><?php // outputs "Array"

<?php
foreach($xml as $element) {
        echo $element . '<br />'; // outputs '<br />' 2 times.
}
?>
<pre>
Username:
<?php print_r($username) ?><?php // nothing ?>
xml:
<?php print_r($xml) ?><?php // full set of all nodes with everything I need just out of reach ?>
</pre>
```

Here is the sample xml.  (It is actually the Magento "app/etc/local.xml" file)

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[secret_username]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[secret_password]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[testing_database]]></dbname>
        <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
        <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
        <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
        <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</default_setup>
```

Comment: do you have a sample xml on this particular question? so that we would know what it looks like?

Comment: @Ghost ok I added the last part of the path. ('default_setup/connection/username').

Answer (score 3):

Youre missing some nodes that path chain you want is:

```
$conn = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection;
$user = (string) $conn->username;
$pass = (string) $conn->password;
```

You could use xpath here but its actually more of a hassle because it will always return an array of nodes (representation of a NodeList) so you would have to loop over it or use `[0]`. Its easier/more readable to just use the direct access. That said to do it with xpath would be:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//default_setup/connection');
if (count($nodes) > 0) {
  $conn = $nodes[0];
  $user = (string) $conn->username;
  $pass = (string) $conn->password;
}
```

Full xml/connection code from my importer in case it helps:

```
// get path for config
$config = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../magento/app/etc/local.xml');

if (!$config) {
    // I've made a terrible mistake.
    throw new Exception('Could not load magento config.');
} else {
    // load up XML
    $conf = new SimpleXMLElement($config, LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);

    // pull the database connection config node
    $conn = $conf->global->resources->default_setup->connection;

    // create a DSN - we will worry about manually setting the attributes ourself
    // since this is a simple one off
    $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $conn->host, $conn->dbname);
    $user = (string) $conn->username;
    $pass = (string) $conn->password;
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);


    if (!$db instanceof PDO) {
        // WOMP, WOMP!
        throw new Exception('Could not create database connection!');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that if someone wants to get the 'connection' node, and it is the only such node in the document, that they have to include every node from global on up in order to get it?

Comment: Yes, unless you use xpath, but as i said in my answer xpath is more of hassle in this specific instance.

Comment: Thanks, your answer works. But I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my xpath usage. I thought I put a valid path and yet I seem to get nothing out of it. Why is my `print_r` not showing anything?

Comment: Also, I am gathering that you only need to use array notation like '->resources[0]->' if there is more than one node with that name... yes?

Comment: Probably your lack of a `//` at the beginning... your path is essentially relative to the root node so if you were to exapnd it you would be looking for `global/default_setup/connection`... Using `//` means anywhere in the doc.

Comment: Re: array notation... yes, thats correct, but in that case i probably **would** use xpath instead.

Comment: Ok I thought your code was working but now it is apparently not. How did you know the full path? You have magento experience?

Comment: I do have Magento experience.. I just did this with a custom import script a couple ago... Please update your question with errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65553/discussion-between-prodigitalson-and-buttle-butkus).

Answer (score 0):

lets get away from your issue to simplify things. here is an example.

the xml file, example.php:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
  <characters>
   <character>
    <name>Ms. Coder</name>
    <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
   </character>
   <character>
    <name>Mr. Coder</name>
    <actor>El Act&#211;r</actor>
   </character>
  </characters>
  <plot>
   So, this language. It's like, a programming language. Or is it a
   scripting language? All is revealed in this thrilling horror spoof
   of a documentary.
  </plot>
  <great-lines>
   <line>PHP solves all my web problems</line>
  </great-lines>
  <rating type="thumbs">7</rating>
  <rating type="stars">5</rating>
 </movie>
</movies>
XML;
?>
```

The php code to extract plot, in your case would be the username:

Example #2 Getting

```
<?php
include 'example.php';

$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo $movies->movie[0]->plot;
?>
```

this came from: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

---

thats ok, it happens.

you can try this, special value * matches all tags.

```
<?php
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book>Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture</book>
 <book>Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Software Design</book>
 <book>Clean Code</book>
</books>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

give it a try. here is the url from php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

if you look below there's more examples.

Comment: You are 1 level deep or so. I have to go a few more levels. Do I have to include the `[0]` for intermediate nodes even if they are unique node names? And my target node is the only one in the whole document that is called "username", so why can't I just GET IT!??!! Frustrating experience, this. Thanks for your help!